# Getting error an "Integer cannot be converted to E[]", but works elsewhere?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, compiler-errors

**EDIT: SOLVED**, a simple mistake on my part. Thank you to those who helped me!

I've looked around and couldn't really find a solution that fits my needs. I am working on coding a generic method that displays the max element of a list. The textbook already provided a line of code for the method: `public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(E[] list)`. Because of this, I am going to assume that my method **requires** `E[]` to be passed as a parameter (important later).

Here is my main class which runs perfectly fine. It fills an Integer array with 25 random ints, and using my `max` method, it returns the highest **element**.

```
public class Question_5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] randX = new Integer[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < randX.length; i++)
        randX[i] = new Random().nextInt();

    System.out.println("Max element in array \'" + randX.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\': " + max(randX));
}

public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(E[] list) {
    E temp = list[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].compareTo(temp) == 1)
            temp = list[i];
        System.out.println("i: " + list[i] + " | Temp: " + temp + " | Byte val: " + list[i].hashCode()); // for debugging
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Before someone mentions to change the parameter from `E[] list` to `Integer[] list`, I'm assuming the textbook wants me to keep it at `E[]` but use an Integer-type array for this problem. Now like I said before, the code works just fine for me, no compiler or run-time errors.

However, my professor wants us to implement JUnit tests, and so I went ahead and whipped this code up:

```
class Question_5_TEST {

@Test
void max() {
    Integer[] randX = new Integer[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < randX.length; i++)
        randX[i] = new Random().nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < randX.length; i++) {
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedMax(randX[i]), Question_5.max(randX[i]), "i = " + i);
    }
}

private <E extends Comparable<E>> E expectedMax(E[] list) {
    Arrays.sort(list);
    return list[0];
}
```

}

**Here is where I am having problems.** I am getting a compiler error saying the following:

> required: E[]
>     found: java.lang.Integer
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to E[]

How come my main class works just fine, but I get a compiler issue within the Testing class? I'm lost as to why this is happening, and like I said previously, I could fix it by changing the parameter type, but is there a way to do it without so?

Thank you.

Comment: Note: your `expectedMax` method reorders the array, and returns the minimum. Better to use `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(list))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `expectedMax` with a single Integer but the method excepts a Array.

So change the Line

```
Assertions.assertEquals(expectedMax(randX[i]), Question_5.max(randX[i]), "i = " + i);
```

to

```
Assertions.assertEquals(expectedMax(randX), Question_5.max(randX[i]), "i = " + i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how I missed this... I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

replace line

```
Assertions.assertEquals(expectedMax(randX[i]), Question_5.max(randX[i]), "i = " + i);
```

with this line
`Assertions.assertEquals(expectedMax(randX), Question_5.max(randX[i]), "i = " + i);`